# I have a list of stickers and i want when I select one or more stickers from this list, stickers are display on my canvas in uwp application

Tags: uwp-xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="Stickers1" Visibility="Collapsed" 
    SelectionChanged="Stickers1_SelectionChanged" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" BorderThickness="50" 
    FontSize="36" Margin="0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource 
    listStickersDataTemplate}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
 <DataTemplate x:Key="listStickersDataTemplate">
     <Grid>
         <Image Source="{Binding Imageurl}" Stretch="Fill" Height="200" Width="200"/>
    </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>`
```

Comment: I have tried this private void Stickers1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selecteditem = e.AddedItems[0] as StickersImageListModel;

            {
                Stickers1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
                ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(selecteditem.Imageurl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
               
            }
            my_canvas.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

Comment: my canvas code<Canvas x:Name="my_canvas" ManipulationMode="All" DragEnter="my_canvas_DragEnter" Drop="my_canvas_Drop" ManipulationDelta="canvas_ManipulationDelta">
                <Canvas.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/MainPage_Images/BG_Main_Page.png"/>
                </Canvas.Background>
                <Image x:Name="img"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="TB1" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="600"/>
            </Canvas>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your `Stickers1_SelectionChanged` event you dont seem to set the `Source` of `img` in your `Canvas`

Something like below should fix it

```
private void Stickers1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selecteditem = e.AddedItems[0] as StickersImageListModel;
    Stickers1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new System.Uri("ms-appx://" + selecteditem.ImageUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
    img.Source = image;
    my_canvas.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;   
}
```

Comment: It will not give any error but my stickers are not display or visible on canvas

Comment: did this answer fix your problem? if so mark as correct answer. If not post correct solution and mark as answer thx

Comment: @vikassharawat no you havent Im afraid :) [Heres how you do it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow)

Comment: but i also want to drag and drop these stickers on my canvas so can you please help me how i do it

Comment: Hi @vikassharawat please open a new question for this separate problem